# Find a function which satisfies an integral equation

Tags: functional-analysis

How can I find a function, $$ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $$ which satisfies the following equation:

$$\cos\left(t^2\right) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{itx}f(x)\,dx$$

Comment: Perhaps you can't. Even if it exists, that does not mean that it can be expressed in terms of [known functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression), or [analytic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function), or even as a definite integral of parameter $t~($like the beta and $\Gamma$ functions, for instance$)$.

Comment: @Lucian -  Actually, I am simply trying to show that all solutions to this equation (if any exist at all) are not probability distributions.